# VueJS - sanitizing output to prevent cross-site scripting attacks

Tags: html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, cross-site, vuejs3

I'm new to VueJS. I start learning about the v-html directive.
My question is: how to sanitize output to prevent cross-site scripting attacks?

Comment: "Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content." — https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanitize for this kind of purposes, but consider that the attack surface may vary based on what you need and what you want to do with v-html, and there are alot of attack ways like add script running on img on error , base64 coded scripts and so on...
so be carefull about using v-html.